# Размер строки в unsigned char*

Tags: char, указатели, c++, строки

Считываю jpeg в unsigned char*.

```
FILE* file;
if((file = fopen("1.jpg", "rb+")) == NULL) {
    printf("Ошибка открытия файла.\n");
    exit(1);
}
fseek (file, 0 , SEEK_END);
int length = ftell(file);
rewind (file);
 std::cout << "length: " << length << std::endl;
data = (unsigned char*)malloc(sizeof(unsigned char)*length);
if (data == NULL) {
    fputs ("Memory error",stderr);
    exit(2);
}
size_t result = fread(data, 1, length, file);
if (result != length) {
    fputs ("Reading error",stderr);
    exit (3);
}
fclose(file); 
std::cout << "strlen(data): " << strlen((char*)data) << std::endl;
std::cout << (char*)data << std::endl;
free(data);
```

В итоге получаю

```
length: 106554 // верное значение
strlen(data): 4
����
```

Чтение проходит корректно, я далее то что хранится в unsigned char *записываю в новый файл jpeg и он открывается нормально.
Как узнать размер значения хранящегося в unsigned char*?

Answer (score 5):

Размер это `length`.

Дело в том, что строковые функции вроде `strlen` в данном случае не применимы. У Вас не строка, у вас **массив байт**. Неоднозначность здесь в том, что в `С` тип `char` из-за своего размер в 1 байт используется и для хранения символьной информации, и для хранения байт.

> Как узнать размер значения хранящегося в unsigned char?

Никак. Нет никаких специализированных функций, которые бы могли вычислить размер буфера, на который ссылается `data`. В данном случае Вы должны хранить 2 переменные - `length` как длинну бинарного буфера и `data` как сам буфер.

Если Вы пишете на С++, то удобнее было бы использовать `std::vector<char>`.

```
std::vector<char> fileData(ftell(file)); // выделили буфер с размером, достаточным 
                                         // для считывания содержимого файла

fread(&fileData[0], 1, fileData.size(), file); // прочитали файл в буфер
```

теперь, если нужно узнать размер буфера, то вызывается `fileData.size()`, если нужно получить доступ к самому буферу, то `&fileData[0]`. Здесь есть одна опасность, при вызове `&fileData[0]`, если в векторе нет элементов, то будет будет осуществлён доступ к невыделеной памяти, что скорее всего приведёт к падению.

Буфер корректно разрушится при вызове деструктора.